# Liferay 6.1 force any "edit control" to appear in a popup

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-6

I'm having issues with the default css and the custom css written by some other company. I'm trying to merge those two but the one affects the other I managed to fix most of the issues but it is really bad written css and very generic.

In order to limit my issues I was thinking to force any type of web-content diplay and porlet edit controls to open into a popup.

Is this possible? google didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understunding your problem, but if the CSS is the cause, I suggest you to fix it instead to look forma a trick.

In order to load web content as dialog, you can create CSS for this purpose on a theme or on each content template.